# Library for RCON clients

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, minecraft, protocols

I wrote a [library](https://gitlab.com/coNQP/mcipc) implementing the [RCON](https://wiki.vg/RCON) protocol to automate interaction with Minecraft servers.
I know that there are already a couple of implementations out there, but neither I found was convincing me, so I re-invented the wheel.

The library will also be featuring an implementation of the [Query](http://wiki.vg/Query) protocol, which is not implemented yet.
This is the reason why the RCON stuff is in a `rcon` subpackage.
However, this review shall only focus on the fully implemented RCON part.

**`mcipc.config.py`**

```
"""Server configuration parser."""

from configparser import ConfigParser
from pathlib import Path

__all__ = ['SERVERS_INI', 'FORTUNE', 'servers']


SERVERS_INI = Path('/etc/mcipc.d/servers.conf')
_SERVERS = ConfigParser()
FORTUNE = Path('/usr/bin/fortune')


def servers():
    """Yields the respective servers."""

    _SERVERS.read(str(SERVERS_INI))

    return {
        section: (_SERVERS[section]['host'], int(_SERVERS[section]['port']),
                  _SERVERS[section].get('passwd'))
        for section in _SERVERS.sections()}
```

**`mcipc.rcon.__init__.py`**

```
"""RCON client library."""

from mcipc.rcon.client import Client
from mcipc.rcon.console import rconcmd
from mcipc.rcon.proto import RequestIdMismatch, PacketType, Packet, RawClient


__all__ = [
    'RequestIdMismatch',
    'rconcmd',
    'PacketType',
    'Packet',
    'RawClient',
    'Client']
```

**`mcipc.rcon.client.py`**

```
"""High level client API."""

from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import datetime
from locale import LC_TIME, getdefaultlocale, setlocale
from logging import getLogger
from subprocess import PIPE, CalledProcessError, check_output

from mcipc.config import FORTUNE
from mcipc.rcon.proto import RequestIdMismatch, RawClient


LOGGER = getLogger(__file__)
_PLAYER_OR_COORDS = TypeError('Must specify either dst_player or coords.')


def _fix_text(text):
    """Fixes text for ascii compliance."""

    return text.replace('\t', '        ')


class OnlinePlayers(namedtuple('OnlinePlayers', ('online', 'max', 'players'))):
    """Online players information."""

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, string):
        """Creates the players information from the server response string."""
        header, players = string.split(':', maxsplit=1)
        players = [player for player in players.split(', ') if player]
        _, _, amount, _, _ = header.split()
        online, max_ = amount.split('/')
        return cls(int(online), int(max_), players)


class Client(RawClient):
    """A high-level RCON client."""

    @property
    def players(self):
        """Returns the players."""
        return OnlinePlayers.from_string(self.run('list'))

    def login(self, passwd):
        """Performs a login, returning False on failure."""
        try:
            return super().login(passwd)
        except RequestIdMismatch:
            return False

    def say(self, message):
        """Broadcast a message to all players."""
        LOGGER.debug('Sending text: "%s".', message)
        return self.run('say', _fix_text(message))

    def tell(self, player, message):
        """Whispers a message to the respective player."""
        return self.run('tell', player, _fix_text(message))

    def mkop(self, player):
        """Makes the respective player an operator."""
        return self.run('op', player)

    def deop(self, player):
        """Revokes operator status from the respective player."""
        return self.run('deop', player)

    def kick(self, player, *reasons):
        """Kicks the respective player."""
        return self.run('kick', player, *reasons)

    def teleport(self, player, dst_player=None, coords=None, yaw_pitch=None):
        """Teleports players."""
        args = [str(player)]

        if dst_player is not None and coords is not None:
            raise _PLAYER_OR_COORDS
        elif dst_player is not None:
            args.append(str(dst_player))
        elif coords is not None:
            coord_x, coord_y, coord_z = coords
            args += [str(coord_x), str(coord_y), str(coord_z)]
        else:
            raise _PLAYER_OR_COORDS

        if yaw_pitch is not None:
            yaw, pitch = yaw_pitch
            args += [str(yaw), str(pitch)]

        return self.run('tp', *args)

    def fortune(self, short=True, offensive=False):
        """Sends a fortune to all players."""
        args = []

        if short:
            args.append('-s')

        if offensive:
            args.append('-o')

        try:
            text = check_output([FORTUNE] + args, stderr=PIPE)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            LOGGER.error('%s is not available.', FORTUNE)
        except CalledProcessError as called_process_error:
            LOGGER.error('Error running %s.', FORTUNE)
            LOGGER.debug(called_process_error.stderr.decode())
        else:
            text = text.decode()
            LOGGER.debug('Fortune text:\n%s', text)
            return self.say(text)

        return False

    def datetime(self, frmt='%c'):
        """Tells all players the current datetime."""
        setlocale(LC_TIME, getdefaultlocale())  # Fix loacale.
        text = datetime.now().strftime(frmt)
        return self.say(text)
```

**`mcipc.rcon.console.py`**

```
"""An interactive console."""

from getpass import getpass

from mcipc.rcon.proto import RequestIdMismatch
from mcipc.rcon.client import Client

__all__ = ['rconcmd']


PS1 = 'RCON> '
EXIT_COMMANDS = ('exit', 'quit')


def _read(prompt, type_=None):
    """Reads input and converts it to the respective type."""

    while True:
        try:
            raw = input(prompt)
        except EOFError:
            continue

        if type_ is not None:
            try:
                return type_(raw)
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                print(f'Invalid {type_}: {raw}.')
                continue

        return raw


def _login(client, passwd):
    """Performs a login."""

    if passwd is None:
        passwd = getpass('Password: ')

    while not client.login(passwd):
        print('Invalid password.')
        passwd = getpass('Password: ')

    return passwd


def rconcmd(host=None, port=None, passwd=None, *, prompt=PS1):
    """Initializes the console."""

    if host is None:
        try:
            host = _read('Host: ')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('\nAborted...')
            return 1

    if port is None:
        try:
            port = _read('Port: ', type_=int)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('\nAborted...')
            return 1

    with Client(host, port) as client:
        try:
            passwd = _login(client, passwd)
        except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
            print('\nAborted...')
            return 1

        while True:
            try:
                command = input(prompt)
            except EOFError:
                print('\nAborted.')
                break
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print()
                continue

            command, *args = command.split()

            if command in EXIT_COMMANDS:
                break

            try:
                result = client.run(command, *args)
            except RequestIdMismatch:
                print('Session timed out. Please login again.')

                try:
                    passwd = _login(client, passwd)
                except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
                    print()
                    continue

            print(result)

    return 0
```

**`mcipc.rcon.credentials.py`**

```
"""RCON server credentials."""

from collections import namedtuple

from mcipc.config import servers

__all__ = ['InvalidCredentialsError', 'Credentials']


class InvalidCredentialsError(ValueError):
    """Indicates invalid credentials."""

    pass


class Credentials(namedtuple('Credentials', ('host', 'port', 'passwd'))):
    """Represents server credentials."""

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, string):
        """Reads the credentials from the given string."""

        try:
            host, port = string.split(':')
        except ValueError:
            try:
                return servers()[string]
            except KeyError:
                raise InvalidCredentialsError(f'No such server: {string}.')

        try:
            port = int(port)
        except ValueError:
            InvalidCredentialsError(f'Not an integer: {port}.')

        try:
            passwd, host = host.rsplit('@', maxsplit=1)
        except ValueError:
            passwd = None

        return cls(host, port, passwd)
```

**`mcipc.rcon.proto.py`**

```
"""Low-level protocol stuff."""

from collections import namedtuple
from enum import Enum
from itertools import chain
from logging import getLogger
from random import randint
from socket import socket
from struct import pack, unpack


__all__ = [
    'RequestIdMismatch',
    'PacketType',
    'Packet',
    'RawClient']


LOGGER = getLogger(__file__)
TAIL = b'\0\0'


class InvalidPacketStructureError(Exception):
    """Indicates an invalid packet structure."""

    pass


class RequestIdMismatch(Exception):
    """Indicates that the sent and received request IDs do not match."""

    def __init__(self, sent_request_id, received_request_id):
        """Sets the sent and received request IDs."""
        super().__init__(sent_request_id, received_request_id)
        self.sent_request_id = sent_request_id
        self.received_request_id = received_request_id


def _rand_int32():
    """Returns a random int32."""

    return randint(0, 2_147_483_647 + 1)


class PacketType(Enum):
    """Available packet types."""

    LOGIN = 3
    COMMAND = 2
    COMMAND_RESPONSE = 0

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value


class Packet(namedtuple('Packet', ('request_id', 'type', 'payload'))):
    """An RCON packet."""

    def __bytes__(self):
        """Returns the packet as bytes."""
        payload = pack('<i', self.request_id)
        payload += pack('<i', int(self.type))
        payload += self.payload.encode()
        payload += TAIL
        return pack('<i', len(payload)) + payload

    @classmethod
    def from_bytes(cls, bytes_):
        """Creates a packet from the respective bytes."""
        request_id, type_ = unpack('<ii', bytes_[:8])
        payload = bytes_[8:-2]
        tail = bytes_[-2:]

        if tail != TAIL:
            raise InvalidPacketStructureError('Invalid tail.', tail)

        return cls(request_id, type_, payload.decode())

    @classmethod
    def from_command(cls, command):
        """Creates a command packet."""
        return cls(_rand_int32(), PacketType.COMMAND, command)

    @classmethod
    def from_login(cls, passwd):
        """Creates a login packet."""
        return cls(_rand_int32(), PacketType.LOGIN, passwd)


class RawClient(socket):
    """An RCON client."""

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        """Sets host an port."""
        super().__init__()
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def __enter__(self):
        """Sets up and conntects the socket."""
        super().__enter__()
        sock = self.socket
        LOGGER.debug('Connecting to socket %s.', sock)
        self.connect(sock)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        """Disconnects the socket."""
        LOGGER.debug('Disconnecting from socket %s.', self.getsockname())
        return super().__exit__(*args)

    @property
    def socket(self):
        """Returns the respective socket."""
        return (self.host, self.port)

    def sendpacket(self, packet):
        """Sends an Packet."""
        bytes_ = bytes(packet)
        LOGGER.debug('Sending %i bytes.', len(bytes_))
        return self.send(bytes_)

    def recvpacket(self):
        """Receives a packet."""
        length, = unpack('<i', self.recv(4))
        payload = self.recv(length)
        return Packet.from_bytes(payload)

    def login(self, passwd):
        """Performs a login."""
        login_packet = Packet.from_login(passwd)
        self.sendpacket(login_packet)
        response = self.recvpacket()

        if response.request_id == login_packet.request_id:
            return True

        raise RequestIdMismatch(
            login_packet.request_id, response.request_id)

    def run(self, command, *arguments):
        """Runs a command."""
        command = ' '.join(chain((command,), arguments))
        command_packet = Packet.from_command(command)
        self.sendpacket(command_packet)
        response = self.recvpacket()

        if response.request_id == command_packet.request_id:
            return response.payload

        raise RequestIdMismatch(
            command_packet.request_id, response.request_id)
```

The library also features two scripts.
One for an interactive console and one for a oneshot client:

**`/usr/bin/rconclt`**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""rconclt.

A Minecraft RCON client.

Usage:
    rconclt <server> datetime [--format=<format>] [options]
    rconclt <server> fortune [--long] [--offensive] [options]
    rconclt <server> <command> [<args>...] [options]

Options:
    --passwd=<passwd>   Specifies the respective RCON password.
    --format=<format>   Specifies the datetime format [default: %c].
    --long              Also generate long fortunes.
    --offensive         Only genenrate offensive fortunes.
    --debug             Enters debug mode.
    --help, -h          Shows this page.
"""
from logging import DEBUG, INFO, basicConfig, getLogger
from sys import exit as exit_

from docopt import docopt

from mcipc.rcon.client import Client
from mcipc.rcon.credentials import InvalidCredentialsError, Credentials


LOGGER = getLogger(__file__)
_LOG_FORMAT = '[%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'


def main(options):
    """Runs the RCON client."""

    log_level = DEBUG if options['--debug'] else INFO
    basicConfig(level=log_level, format=_LOG_FORMAT)

    try:
        host, port, passwd = Credentials.from_string(options['<server>'])
    except InvalidCredentialsError as error:
        LOGGER.error(error)
        exit_(2)

    if passwd is None:
        passwd = options['--passwd'] or ''

    with Client(host, port) as client:
        if client.login(passwd):
            if options['datetime']:
                result = client.datetime(frmt=options['--format'])
            elif options['fortune']:
                result = client.fortune(
                    short=not options['--long'],
                    offensive=options['--offensive'])
            else:
                result = client.run(options['<command>'], *options['<args>'])

            if result:
                LOGGER.info(result)
        else:
            LOGGER.error('Failed to log in.')
            exit_(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(docopt(__doc__))
```

**`/usr/bin/rconcmd`**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""An interactive RCON console."""

from sys import exit as exit_
from mcipc.rcon.console import rconcmd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit_(rconcmd())
```

I'd appreciate any critique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get rid of the `struct` module used in `proto.py`, after I learned that `int` has a built-in [`from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) classmethod.

Furthermore I migrated from `collections.namedtuple` to `typing.NamedTuple` because I personally find this kind of subclassing more readable.

Finally, I outsourced the exceptions into an own module and added type hints:

```
"""Low-level protocol stuff."""

from enum import Enum
from logging import getLogger
from random import randint
from typing import NamedTuple

from mcipc.common import BaseClient
from mcipc.rcon.exceptions import InvalidPacketStructureError, \
    RequestIdMismatchError, InvalidCredentialsError


__all__ = ['Type', 'Packet', 'Client']


LOGGER = getLogger(__file__)
TAIL = b'\0\0'


def _rand_uint32() -> int:
    """Returns a random unsigned int32."""

    return randint(0, 4_294_967_295 + 1)


class Type(Enum):
    """Available packet types."""

    LOGIN = 3
    COMMAND = 2
    RESPONSE = 0

    def __bytes__(self):
        """Returns the integer value as little endian."""
        return self.value.to_bytes(4, 'little')     # pylint: disable=E1101


class Packet(NamedTuple):
    """An RCON packet."""

    request_id: int
    type: Type
    payload: bytes

    def __bytes__(self):
        """Returns the packet as bytes."""
        payload = self.request_id.to_bytes(4, 'little')
        payload += bytes(self.type)
        payload += self.payload
        payload += TAIL
        size = len(payload).to_bytes(4, 'little')
        return size + payload

    @classmethod
    def from_bytes(cls, bytes_: bytes):
        """Creates a packet from the respective bytes."""
        request_id = int.from_bytes(bytes_[:4], 'little')
        type_ = int.from_bytes(bytes_[4:8], 'little')
        payload = bytes_[8:-2]
        tail = bytes_[-2:]

        if tail != TAIL:
            raise InvalidPacketStructureError('Invalid tail.', tail)

        return cls(request_id, Type(type_), payload)

    @classmethod
    def from_command(cls, command: str):
        """Creates a command packet."""
        return cls(_rand_uint32(), Type.COMMAND, command.encode())

    @classmethod
    def from_login(cls, passwd: str):
        """Creates a login packet."""
        return cls(_rand_uint32(), Type.LOGIN, passwd.encode())

    @property
    def text(self) -> str:
        """Returns the payload as text."""
        return self.payload.decode()


class Client(BaseClient):
    """An RCON client."""

    def communicate(self, packet: Packet) -> Packet:
        """Sends and receives a packet."""
        self._socket.send(bytes(packet))
        header = self._socket.recv(4)
        length = int.from_bytes(header, 'little')
        payload = self._socket.recv(length)
        response = Packet.from_bytes(payload)

        if response.request_id == packet.request_id:
            return response

        raise RequestIdMismatchError(packet.request_id, response.request_id)

    def login(self, passwd: str) -> bool:
        """Performs a login."""
        packet = Packet.from_login(passwd)

        try:
            self.communicate(packet)
        except RequestIdMismatchError:
            raise InvalidCredentialsError()

        return True

    def run(self, command: str, *arguments: str) -> str:
        """Runs a command."""
        command = ' '.join((command,) + arguments)
        packet = Packet.from_command(command)
        response = self.communicate(packet)
        return response.text
```